# Marquee tool help

Tags: adobe-photoshop, marquee-tool

So if I draw a box with marquee tool  and want to move it , it just creates anther box   and if I want a different box the first box doesn't disappear--    It used to ..

Why?
Please help

Thanks Alicia

Comment: Which program are we talking about? Photoshop?

Comment: sorry-- yes.. newest version

Comment: I've had a few similar problems with the newer versions of Photoshop. I'm using CPU rendering. It all works like it's supposed to but fragments of earlier selections seem to get stuck on the screen until I zoom in or out. Sometimes a new selection also isn't visible before changing view. Is it a visual glitch like that or does it also affect functionality?

Comment: functionality.. .. trying to move the box just creates another box or an extension to first box... impossible to move the one i want

Answer (score 1):

To move or change a selection, choose: Select->Transform Selection.

To move or transform the selected pixels:

1. Make sure you have a raster layer selected in the layer panel
2. With the move tool, click on the selection and you'll be given the standard transform handles
3. Make whatever transformations you'd like

Comment: perfect... Just created box and moved it   : )